# How do I submit a Visual Studio bug if the normal channels are not working?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using Visual Studio 2013.  It keeps crashing under certain circumstances, so I'm trying to submit a bug report.

I have tried *HELP > Feedback > Report a Bug*, but after logging in at *connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio* it either has a message saying that I am not authorized to submit feedback for this connection (whatever that means), or the page is blank under the top banner.  In either case, I can click the "Feedback" link on the banner, which takes me to a list of the most recently submitted items.  From that list, there is no direct way to add an item, but the instructions say "After searching, the option to submit new feedback will be enabled."  If I search (which takes literally minutes), I then get a "Submit Feedback" button at the top of the list.  If I click this, it goes back to the blank page I saw before I clicked "Feedback" on the banner.

How am I supposed to submit my bug?  How can I report this failure of the bug reporting service?

Answer (score 0):

If you are having troubles submitting with the built in tools you can go to https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio and manually submit a bug report there.

Using the built in tools are preferred because you can record a ETL trace and steps showing how to recreate the bug. When you post to connect they may ask you to do those things manually.

However, it is unlikely any bug in Visual Studio 2013 will be fixed. They only release updates for the current publicly released version of Visual Studio which is Visual Studio 2015 currently.